# Generate xsd from xml, validate xml, generate class/objects from xml/xsd

Tags: xml, class, windows-phone-7, object, xsd

Please assume I know nothing about anything.

I am new to windows phone development.

I have an xml as follows - its not a file - its an XDocument generated from string which came from server

```
<User>
<Number>00000</Number>
<Id>1234</Id>
<TextKey>A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A1A</TextKey>
<Agent>WindowsPhone</Agent>
</User>
```

First of all, I need to generate an xsd for this xml
Then I need to validate this xml against the xsd on the windows phone platform
then if the xml is valid, I need to generate objects/class from it(???)
I've read about xsd.exe XML Schema Definition tool
how do I go on using it??
Any other way to do all the above in visual studio 2012???

Comment: If you generate the XSD from the XML then the XML will ALWAYS validate correctly with that XSD, so the validation step is useless

Comment: @MiMo I just need to generate xsd once and then store it in the app directory, so that when the app is released it can validate the xmls it receives with the ones stored
Anyways, I was able to generate the xsd files from xsd.exe tool
New question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105126/deserialise-xml-response-from-server